# ThreadLocalRandom or AtomicInteger

Tags: java, random

I have a need to generate non-overlapping numbers (random or incremental doesnt matter as each generated number is unique) in multiple threads. I think I have two choices

1. Use AtomicInteger and share it across all threads
2. Use ThreadLocalRandom with different start and end ranges for each thread

I need this to be very fast and also the numbers should be unique across all the threads. Which one is better?

Comment: Will UUID wont work for you

Comment: @WandMaker No. it has to be numerics

Comment: ThreadLocalRandom  seems to be the way for you as also indicated in official java docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1 will be slower because `AtomicInteger` provides thread safety through the use of a `volatile int` - meaning modifications or reads must *always* fetch from/write to RAM, which will always be slower than reading/writing in the processor's cache memory.

Option 2 might be faster (depending on how much time it takes to calculate the next number in the sequence vs. a memory fetch), but you run the risk (albeit small) of generating duplicate numbers randomly.

Might I suggest a third option? Use a thread local `int` or `long` with a pre-defined range. You won't have to worry about cache coherency as only one thread will have access to each primitive counter you store. You still run the risk of wrap-around, but you will know exactly when it happens, unlike the risk of running into duplicates on a random number sequence.

Comment: I am not sure how there can be duplicates. Look at this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextInt(int,%20int)

Comment: @Pangea as with any RNG you have the chance of running duplicates.

Comment: @Pangea You can easily have duplicates - we're dealing with more than one random number generator, so regardless of how numbers are randomly generated, you could potentially get duplicates across differing sequences. With a counter, you're at least guaranteed to get through the entire number line before you get a duplicate.

Comment: @JohnVint Is it a theoretical limitation or practical one?

Comment: @CodeBlind I am providing the upper and lowerbounds for each thread which aren't going to overlap.

Comment: @Pangea - ah yes, short-term memory failure on my part ;) Still, RNGs can't guarantee that you will never get a duplicate result because they are finite. The best you can do is exhaust all 32- or 64-bit numbers (depending on whether you use an `int` or `long`) before you run into one you've seen before, and they cannot guarantee that this won't happen *before* the search space is exhausted, unlike with using a counter.

Comment: There's a great chance of generating duplicates. An RNG that prevents duplicates is more predictable than one that doesn't. It would be a flaw in the RNG. A counter will be faster and safer. Clearly the best answer.